# Fastest way to iterate conditionally backward or forward

Tags: c, loops, optimization

I can think of at least three ways to choose the direction of a loop.

Two loops, one condition at the beginning (maybe the fastest ?):

```
if (!backwards)
  for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
  // code
  }
else
  for (int i = end; i >= 0; i--){
  // code
  }
```

Loop on a number of elements, test and increment inside (I use this one):

```
for (int l = 0; l < max_len; l++) {
  // code
  if (!backward)
    i++;
  else
    i--;
}
```

Use an variable increment and end value (maybe the worst ?)

```
if (backward)
  inc = -1;
else
  inc = 1;
for (int i = 0; i != end; i += inc) {
  // code
}
```

Which way is faster ? Does the compiler optimizes it in every case ?

Comment: 2nd solution is proabably worst (and wrong BTW, I let you find out why). What makes you think the 3rd solution is worst ?

Comment: 3rd solution is wrong as well. Start value is a bit off.

Comment: Woops, thanks! Yes, for the last one the end shall end+1 or end-1 depending on the increment. For the first one I don't see why it should seem off though ?

Comment: It's not possible to answer "fastest"-type questions at this level, since the answer might be different depending on so many factors (like CPU specs, optimization, caches, and so on).

Comment: My first thought is that the first is the fastest

Comment: different for intel 4004 and i7-7700

Answer (score 5):

Discussing performance without a specific system in mind is not very meaningful. The things to consider here, for a "generic computer", would be

- The actual machine code generated. Fewer CPU ticks gives faster programs on any CPU.
- The number of branches. Fewer branches means better branch prediction possibilities and the CPU can utilize instruction cache memory, if present.
- The actual work done by the loop. This could potentially be the most important part. Suppose the loop does something with an array. If the array is accessed sequentially, from the top of data to the bottom of the data, it means that the CPU can utilize data cache.

An old way of improving the machine code was to write down-counting loops whenever possible, because that would result in a "branch if zero" instruction, which is ever so slightly faster than a "branch if equal to". However, this technique originates from the dark ages when compilers were crap. With modern, optimizing compilers, the order of iteration shouldn't be a performance issue. So this trick is mostly obsolete.

Apart from that, the different loops may yield ever so slightly more/less efficient code compared to each other, depending on system. You could disassemble the different versions and check, but this is a very minor concern.

Regarding branches, the 3rd version is obviously much better than the others, since it only contains one single branch - the check against the loop iterator, which gives the loop itself. 1st version is worse and 2nd version is much worse.

Depending on what the loop actually does, the 3rd version may not be ideal for data cache however. Impossible to say.

Overall, one of these two versions are possibly the most efficient:

```
for(size_t i=start; i!=end; i+=inc)
```

or maybe

```
size_t offset = backwards ? n-1 : 0;
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  size_t index = i - offset;
  arr[index] = something;
}
```

But the only way to tell is to actually benchmark and disassemble. And to do that, you need to specify a specific system.

Comment: The reason down-counting can be faster is the sequence is decrement, loop if not zero, versus up-counting which is increment, compare, loop if not equal.

Comment: @rcgldr Which isn't something the programmer should concern themselves with unless they are writing assembler. In modern programming, writing such down-counting loops is a perfect example of "pre-mature optimization".

Comment: My comment was to explain the "old" reason for down counting on "old" systems, in some cases where the performance did matter. This would not apply to normal "modern" systems.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the choices that you have chosen, I would avoid method 2 as it adds checks/branches on each element you can probably avoid in the critical loop. If you know a priori if you desired element element is near the back or front of the array, then method 1 or 3 may be the best.

Comparing 1 and 3 is less straight forward. I believe on the Intel X86 processor, the performance will be identical to the for loop you have in example 1. That is ++i and i += 1 will both translate to an add instruction, and the NE (not equal) comparison would be equivalent to a LE (less than equal). However, in general, to know for sure you need to check the disassembly of the processor/compiler you are using.

Note: what was also said in this thread that a countdown loop (compare with 0) may provide a slight speed benefit on some processors. In addition, some processors will yield a slight performance gain if you use a preincrement ++i as opposed to the post increment you have in your examples.

As an aside: If you want to check all the elements in an array structure,and if your c library supports parallelism, a Parallel For may prove to be the fastest where you divide the number of elements by the number of processor threads.

An example of using a Parallel For with 4 processor threads: If your array contains 1 million elements and you have 4 threads, you can have thread 1 iterate over 0 to 249.999, thread 2 250,000 to 499,999, thread 3 500,000 to 749,999, and thread 4 750,000 to 999,999 in a simulataneous fashion.  The total theoretical gain would be 4X - minus some overhead plus the time to wait for the slowest thread to finish. (in this case this time amount should be minimal).

Comment: This is tagged C. Please don't post an answer for a different programming language.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer to make it C compliant.